# SSIS (2012) - Project deployment model - Project parameters or Master package parameter binding

Tags: ssis, integration, etl

I am using project deployment model to deploy the SSIS(2012) solution. I use a parent package to execute other child packages.  What is the best way (or best practice) to pass parameters to child packages?

When should I use Project level Parameters and Master package parameter bindings? What are the Pros and cons with the approach ? Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach is to use Project Level Parameters for parameters which are common to several if not all of the packages inside your project. For instance, server and database names. This way, I only need to update them in one place.

I would use the package level parameters for parameters which are needed by that package only and would have values specific to that package only.

By the way, if a parameter is set at Project level (Project.params), then you don't need to pass it from Master to child anymore. Child packages can directly use them. You would pass parameters only if the parameter value is generated only at run-time by the parent package.

It is not directly related but I have documented a solution to automated SSIS 2012 deployment and configuration management which you might be interested with. It's a 3-part series. Please find the link to the first one below:

http://vaniecastro.com/2015/07/19/automate-ssis-2012-project-deployment-and-configuration-management-using-powershell-part-1/

Comment: Per the site rules, you need to disclose your affiliation with any links provided, otherwise they can be considered spam.  Additionally, link-only answers are not allowed; while this one isn't a link-only answer, you have a number of other answers currently up for review and flagged for deletion in the Low Quality Review queue because of this.